# How to show in the Django administration only the data corresponding to the current user's company

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-permissions

I'm developing a project in Django. I have several registered companies, and all models are based on the company. My question is this: how can I do that when a user enters the administration can only see the data of their company.

```py
models.py

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class XUser(User):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    card = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(XUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

For example, when a user enters the administration they can only see the books that belong to their company.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an admin mixin for doing this by overriding the default queryset.

```py
class CompanyModelMixin:
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)

        # return a filtered queryset
        return qs.filter(company=request.user.company)
```

And then you can use this in any ModelAdmin.

```py
@admin.register(Book)
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, CompanyModelMixin):
    pass
```

Comment: It don't work, maybe because user don't have a company field. This field is in XUser model. Can be that?

Comment: This was just an example. You can add that company field in the queryset yourself. I guess that you are using Custom User model `XUser` so I used `request.user.company`

Comment: Imagine now that I have another model, for example Paragraph, which contains as a foraneal key Company and Book. When I try to create a Paragraph instance in the django management form, it shows me all the books and I want it to only show me the ones that belong to the user's Company. Any ideas?